# How to make custom made lightbox to autoplay with animations

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, css-animations, lightbox, image-gallery

I wanted to make [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox) custom made lightbox to autoplay with some simple animation. Is it possible to autoplay the sliders with simple jquery code or do i need to add some external pulgins. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to the code for auto-play thing :

```js
var time = 1000;

setInterval(function(){
  var columns = $('#myModal .column');
  var cur = $('img.active').closest('.column');
  var ind = columns.index(cur);
  ind = (ind + 1) % columns.length;
  columns.eq(ind).find('img').click();
}, time);
```

**NOTE :** Change in HTML structure, or CSS classes may affect its functioning.